# How can I read data from a csv file and store it in my database file in sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv

I have a static csv file. I want to covert all the data in the csv file to a database so that I can access the data in the csv file in my application. I have searched a lot about this. But still I'm was not able to find something that served my cause. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I figured it out, a csv file can be converted into a sqlite database file using a tool like the sqlite firefox extension. The converted file can then be used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that's going to automatically take a CSV file and populate your database. At least, you need to map each value in the file to a DB row yourself. You are going to have to write your own code to process the CSV file (using a library or otherwise), and write the code to insert each CSV "row" into SQLite.

Note that processing a CSV file for which you control the format is very simple. you can just use a FileRead and String.split(). then, again assuming that value N in a CSV row maps to col N in the DB, you can do,

```
private static final List<String> COLUMNS = new ArrayList<String>() {
  add("NAME"); add("ADDRESS"); add("ZIPCODE"); ...;
}

SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedRead(new FileReader("foo.csv"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  Iterator cols = COLUMNS.iterator();
  String[] vals = line.split("\\s*,");
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  for (String v: vals) {
    cv.put(cols.next(), v);
  }
  db.insert(..., cv);
}
```

In this example, you must ensure that the order of the columns defined in COLUMNS matches exactly with the order of the values in each CSV row.

Answer (score -1):

First of all import your csv file in your program
you did not tell about your program
if you are using .net load your csv file into datagridview and then save whole data into sqlite database..